# How to get the Kraus operator $M_0=\sqrt{1-p}\, I$ for the depolarizing channel, from its isometric representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-operation, density-matrix, kraus-representation, projection-operator

[image: Notes on Kraus operators of depolarizing channel from http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf]

I am confused as to how we get $M_{0} = \sqrt{1-p} I$ and the following $M_{1}, M_{2}, M_{3}$.

The above notes say that we should partially trace over the environment in the $|{0}\rangle, |{1}\rangle, |{2}\rangle, |{3}\rangle$ basis. However, I thought that that would mean we would obtain $M_{0} = \sqrt{1-p}|{\psi}\rangle_{A}$, how do we lose the state $|{\psi}\rangle$ in the partial trace process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unitary representation specifies how the isometry $U$ acts on pure states. The channel $\Phi$ is related to $U$ by $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}_E[U\rho U^\dagger]$. Notice that on pure states this reads
$$\Phi(|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|) = \sum_a \mathbb{P}[(I\otimes \langle a|_E)U|\psi\rangle]$$
where I used the shorthand notation $\mathbb{P}[|\phi\rangle]\equiv |\phi\rangle\!\langle \phi|$.
Furthermore, you get a Kraus representation of $\Phi$ as the operators $M_a \equiv (I\otimes \langle a|_E)U$.

In your example you have $(I\otimes \langle 0|_E)U|\psi\rangle=\sqrt{1-p} |\psi\rangle$ for all $|\psi\rangle$. This means that $(I\otimes \langle 0|_E)U=\sqrt{1-p} I$, or equivalently, $M_0=\sqrt{1-p}I$.